# How to use bounding box in Love2d?

Tags: lua, love2d

I've been using some extremely bulky code to detect collision between simple objects, and I've heard about bounding boxes. I can't find any tutorials on how to use it, so I'm asking about how to use it. Here is how I detect collision:

```
    function platform.collision()
if player.x + player.width / 2 <= platform.x + platform.width and
    player.x + player.width / 2 >= platform.x and
    player.y + player.height <= platform.y + platform.height and 
    player.y + player.height >= platform.y then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) has a rather concise article on [2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection). Being the MDN, the examples are in `javascript`, but are easily translated to, and applicable in, any language - including Lua.

Let's take a look:

> #### Axis-Aligned Bounding Box
>
> One of the simpler forms of collision detection is between two rectangles that are axis aligned — meaning no rotation. The algorithm works by ensuring there is no gap between any of the 4 sides of the rectangles. Any gap means a collision does not exist.

Their example, translated to Lua:

```
local rect1 = { x = 5, y = 5, width = 50, height = 50 }
local rect2 = { x = 20, y = 10, width = 10, height = 10 }

if 
    rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width and
    rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x and
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height and
    rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y 
then
    -- collision detected!
end

-- filling in the values =>

if 
    5 < 30 and
    55 > 20 and
    5 < 20 and
    55 > 10
then
    -- collision detected!
end
```

A [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/knam8/), again in JavaScript, demonstrates this well.

---

Here's a quick (and imperfect) Love2D example you can throw into a `main.lua` and play around with.

```
local function rect (x, y, w, h, color)
    return { x = x, y = y, width = w, height = h, color = color }
end

local function draw_rect (rect)
    love.graphics.setColor(unpack(rect.color))

    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', rect.x, rect.y,
        rect.width, rect.height)
end

local function collides (one, two)
    return (
        one.x < two.x + two.width and
        one.x + one.width > two.x and
        one.y < two.y + two.height and
        one.y + one.height > two.y
    )
end

local kp = love.keyboard.isDown
local red = { 255, 0, 0, 255 }
local green = { 0, 255, 0, 255 }
local blue = { 0, 0, 255, 255 }

local dim1 = rect(5, 5, 50, 50, red)
local dim2 = rect(20, 10, 60, 40, green)

function love.update ()
    if kp('up') then
        dim2.y = dim2.y - 1
    end

    if kp('down') then
        dim2.y = dim2.y + 1
    end

    if kp('left') then
        dim2.x = dim2.x - 1
    end

    if kp('right') then
        dim2.x = dim2.x + 1
    end

    dim2.color = collides(dim1, dim2) and green or blue
end

function love.draw ()
    draw_rect(dim1)
    draw_rect(dim2)
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped since I'm trying to make an efficient platformer game. I've only known lua for about a week, so anything I can take in helps.

Comment: @LucaLizaranzu Well then, welcome to Lua! Here's a few general resources to help you on your way. If you're like me and you enjoy reading these might come in handy: [Lua Reference Manual (For 5.1)](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/), [Love2D Wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Programming in Lua (A Book)](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html). Cheers & good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Oka explained it very well. This works for everything rectangular, not rotated and axis aligned. And you even already did it that way. This is great for buttons and the like!

But what I like doing is using (invisible) circles around objects and see if these collide. This works for everything where height is about the same as the width (which is the case for many sidescrolling platformers or top-down RPGs).
It's quite handy if you want to have the object centered at the current position. And it's especially helpful to simulate a finger on a touchscreen device, because a finger is quite a bit bigger than a mouse cursor. ;)

Here's an example on how to use this method. You can copy it as an actual game, it'll work.

```
--[[ Some initial default settings. ]]

function love.load()
    settings = {
        mouseHitbox = 5,   -- A diameter around the mouse cursor.
        -- For a finger (thouchscreen) this could be bigger!
    }

    objects = {
        [1] = {
            x = 250,   -- Initial X position of object.
            y = 200,   -- Initial Y position of object.
            hitbox = 100,   -- A diameter around the CENTER of the object.
            isHit = false    -- A flag for when the object has been hit.
        },
        [2] = {
            x = 400,
            y = 250,
            hitbox = 250,
            isHit = false
        }
    }
end

--[[ This is the actual function to detect collision between two objects. ]]

function collisionDetected(x1,y1,x2,y2,d1,d2)
    -- Uses the x and y coordinates of two different points along with a diameter around them.
    -- As long as these two diameters collide/overlap, this function returns true!
    -- If d1 and/or d2 is missing, use the a default diameter of 1 instead.
    local d1 = d1 or 1
    local d2 = d2 or 1
    local delta_x = x2 - x1
    local delta_y = y2 - y1
    local delta_d = (d1 / 2) + (d2 / 2)
    if ( delta_x^2 + delta_y^2 < delta_d^2 ) then
        return true
    end
end

--[[ Now, some LÖVE functions to give the collisionDetection() some context. ]]

function love.draw()
    for i=1,#objects do   -- Loop through all objects and draw them.
        if ( objects[i].isHit ) then
            love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)   -- If an object is hit, it will flash red for a frame.
            objects[i].isHit = false
        else
            love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
        end
        love.graphics.circle("line", objects[i].x, objects[i].y, objects[i].hitbox/2)
    end
end

-- You can use the following to check, if any object has been clicked on (or tapped on a touch screen device).

function love.mousepressed(x,y,button)
    if ( button == 1 ) then
        local i = objectIsHit(x,y)   -- Check, if an object has been hit.
        if ( i ) then
            -- The object number 'i' has been hit. Do something with this information!
            objects[i].isHit = true
        end
    end
end

function objectIsHit(x,y)
    for i=1,#objects do   -- Loop through all objects and see, if one of them has been hit.
        if ( collisionDetected(x, y, objects[i].x, objects[i].y, settings.mouseHitbox, objects[i].hitbox) ) then
            return i   -- This object has been hit!
        end
    end
end

-- For the sake of completeness: You can use something like the following to check, if the objects themselves collide.
-- This would come in handy, if the objects would move around the screen and then bounce from each other, for example.

function love.update(dt)
    if ( collisionDetected(objects[1].x, objects[1].y, objects[2].x, objects[2].y, objects[1].hitbox, objects[2].hitbox) ) then
        -- The objects collided. Do something with this information!
    end
end
```

As you can see, the `collisionDetection()` function is quite easy and intuitive to use.

Hopefully I could give you some more insight. **And have fun with LÖVE 2D!** :)